# In Voltron, where can we hear the exact quote "unleash the Robeast"?

Tags: voltron-legendary-defender

This is [Lotor's catch-phrase](https://www.absoluteanime.com/voltron/lotor), but I've scrolled through a bunch of videos and the closest I've gotten is "[launch the Robeast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SFQar4066o&t=13m)".

Zarkon or Haggar saying it would be great too.